# Accessing SVN repo from server side

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, repository

Question: How can I set my server up to access files in a repository?

---

Info: I have this small server project I've been working on now for about 8 months. I've gotten some things accomplished, notable for this question are that I have both Apache and SVN running. What I'm looking to do is set up Apache to access files inside of a repository. It would be a lot nicer to my web development via a repository than FTP. (I'm a college student, left my server at home. So all my management is done remotely.)

I had hoped that the most recent commit on server side would just be in a folder than I could access, such seems to not be the case. Is there something I must do make the last commit show up so that Apache can load those files? or do i have to actually check the code out to a different folder on the server and have Apache access those files?

---

Details:

Ubuntu Linux 9.04

Apache 2.2.11

SVN 1.5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a `post-commit` hook to update your local checkout on your server, something like putting :

```
/usr/bin/svn update --accept theirs-full /home/where/your/checkout/is
```

in your `post-commit` hook file in your repository's `hooks` directory. (The `--accept theirs-full` is there in case you one day modify the checkout and there's a conflict later.)

Comment: how do i do an initial check out? as I currently don't have this checked out on the server at all. I typed what you gave me there and it resulted in: Skipped '/projects/www'  I'm guessing I have to check out to somewhere locally before I can do an update.

Comment: You do the initial checkout the same way you'd do it somewhere else, `svn checkout http://....`

Comment: Oh, and you have to do it with the user the web server runs in, as the `svn update` will be done by that user.

Comment: ah, there we go. that's what i was looking for. Thanks!